# bassistance jQuery form validation plugin - email error before submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using this plugin:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

For JQuery form validation.  Everything is working great except for the email field.  As soon as I start typing in that field, the "Please enter a valid email address." message appears, even though what I've typed so far is correct.

In the documentation (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) it says:

> "Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before
>   submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through
>   fields without getting annoying messages - he won't get bugged before
>   he had the chance to actually enter a correct value"

But this doesn't seem to happen for the email field.

This problem can also be seen in the author's demo:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Is there an option/workaround for this behaviour?

Comment: In the demo, it is working correct. Where is your code? What is your mail id format? How did you try?

Comment: I've tested the demo (http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) in Firefox, Chrome, IE7/8/9 on several PCs and the behaviour is the same. Start typing in the email box and the "Please enter a valid email address." message appears.  Can you confirm this doesn't happen for you?  
I can add my html if needed, but its the basic implementation found here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: I'm running the example with jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.0pre, and jquery-1.7.2.js - displays error message only on blur

Comment: Thanks politus. Where did you find 1.11.0 pre?

Comment: latest is on github https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/archive/master.zip

Comment: Thanks for the link, politus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through
>   fields without getting annoying messages - he won't get bugged before
>   he had the chance to actually enter a correct value"*
>
> But this doesn't seem to happen for the email field.

It's not just with the `email` rule.  You can see the same behavior on the `minlength` rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/f3sxF/

> Is there an option/workaround for this behaviour?

You could use the pre-release version which seems to fix this.  However, rather than risking new bugs by the use of a "pre-release" version of the plugin on your production site, you could simply use a modified version of the `onkeyup` callback function...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
        if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === '') {
            return;
        } else if (element.name in this.submitted ) {
            this.element(element);
        }
    },
    // your other options
});
```

Using the above, all `onkeyup` validation is ignored until the form is submitted for the first time, or until the user tabs out of a field which contains entered data.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/wNj4n/

Comment: Thanks Sparky and co.  I'm very happy with the workaround - it solves the problem, and like you say, its safer than running a prerelease :)

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is fixed in the latest [jquery-validate.js on github](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/archive/master.zip).  The bug was reported  as

> 'E-mail validation fires immediately when text is in the field'

[bug report and discussion here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/521)

Comment: In this jsFiddle, the behavior seems to be the same on the `minlength` rule. http://jsfiddle.net/f3sxF/